# detectar a todos los checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Tengo 3 checkbox, y necesito que cada uno me cambie el fondo de un color. Consigo que el primero,cambie de color, pero los demás, no sé cómo hacer para referirme a ellos, probé con el queryselectorAll, pero no me funciona.

```js
'use strict'


let box = document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]'); 

function color(){
    if(box.checked)
    document.body.style.background='red';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
        <input type="checkbox" value="red" onchange ="color()"/>Rojo
        <input type="checkbox" value="blue" onchange ="color()"/>Azul  
        <input type="checkbox" value="gren" onchange ="color()"/>Verde


<script src="ejercicio4.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que te conviene usar para esto es un input tipo `radio`, ya que **cuando varios radio tienen el mismo `name` no podrás seleccionar más de uno a la vez**. Si se trata de cambiar el color de fondo en base a ese criterio, será muy complicado con el checkbox, ya que podrías tener varios seleccionados al mismo tiempo, teniendo que recurrir a un procedimiento sumplemetario para hacer que el checkbox se comporte como si fuese un radio.

Si usas un radio el proceso es muy simple. Ni siquiera tendrías que usar el `if`, simplemente obtienes el value del radio **dentro de la función** y en base a él cambias el color de fondo. Eso es todo.

Otra cosa, tenías en error al escribir `gren`, debe ser `green`.

```js
'use strict'

function color() {
  var cssColor = document.querySelector('input[name="colors"]:checked').value;
  console.log(cssColor);
  document.body.style.background = cssColor;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="radio" name="colors" value="red" onchange="color()" />Rojo
  <input type="radio" name="colors" value="blue" onchange="color()" />Azul
  <input type="radio" name="colors" value="green" onchange="color()" />Verde


  <script src="ejercicio4.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```